# Is it possible to see the source code of oracle inbuilt function

Tags: oracle

I am trying to see the source code of oracle inbuilt functions. I am doing this because i want to see how oracle implements its own functions. After doing a bit of research online i found that i can see function of standard package in the file
"stdspec.sql" and "stdbody.sql". I looked for inbuilt function "LIKE" and found 
the below code:

```
 function 'LIKE' (str VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
                   pat VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET str%CHARSET)
        return BOOLEAN;
```

I want to see the implementation of this functions. So is it possible to see that? If yes can somebody please help me to achieve that.

Comment: I guess it is proprietary native code and you won't be able to see its definition without some sort of reverse engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't see the code of the built-in SQL functions. That is compiled into the Oracle binary. And as Oracle is not an open source database, you can't get access to Oracle's source code.

You can't even see the code of most of the Oracle provided PL/SQL procedures and packages as they have been encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you said that oracle is not free so i cant see its source code, so can i see it for mysql as it is opensource ??

Comment: While MySQL is indeed open source, you won't see the source of Oracle's functions there. If you want to _study_ the source code of a DBMS, I suggest you look at Postgres instead.